# How do I get the $language object inside a form builder?

Tags: forms

I have this necesity to use $language inside `MY_MODULE_form($form, &$form_state)` function and it seems is not available. I tried to define it as global, but it displays blank.

```
global $language_content;
dpm($language_content->language);
```

My simplified structure of `MY_MODULE_form()` looks like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
global $language_content;
$form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
  );
  $form['back'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div class="link" ><a href="/project/$LANG-HERE/my/home">'.t('Back').'</a></div>',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

I found a hardcoded PHP solution:

```
if(strpos($haystack, 'en')) {
    $back_path = "/project/en/my/home";
    }
  if(strpos($haystack, 'fi')) {
    $back_path = "/project/fi/my/home";
  }
  $form['continue-shopping'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div class="link" ><a href="'.$back_path.'">'.t('Back').'</a></div>',
  );
```

I am looking however to something more elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) (or [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7), which justs generates the URL) for generating links; then you, don't have to worry about the current language, base path, whatever clean URLs are enabled or not.

```
l(t('Back'), 'my/home');
```

That said, `global $language` should always work.

Comment: Amazing! This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, you saved my hardcoding future.

Answer (score 1):

Using `global $language;` should always get you the language object.